# Условие. Вывод без дублей из под foreach?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$result = array_flatten($mass); // обычный массив

?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Сайт </th>
        <th>ИКС</th>
        </tr>
    <tbody> 
        <?php
            foreach ($result as $url => $iks)
            {
                if ($iks >= 10) // если ИКС больше или равен 10

                {
                    $quer = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `" . PREFIX . "_sites` WHERE `url` = '" . $url . "'");
                    if (!$query->num_rows)
                    { //если нет в БД, то заносим

            ?>
                <tr>    
                <td><?php echo $iks; ?></td>    
                <td><?php echo $url; ?></td>
                </tr>   
                <?php
                        $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `" . PREFIX . "_sites`(`url`,`iks`) VALUES ('" . $url . "', '" . $iks . "')");
                        echo 'OK';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'NO';
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>          
</table>
```

И выдает собака: ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok ok okNONONONONONONONONONONO

Т.е. Как сделать условие, чтоб если есть (хотябы один) ИКС от 10 - то выводило 1н раз OK
И соотв. если нет ничего (меньше ИКС 10) - выводило 1н раз - NO

Как из цикла вытащить?
Спасибо за ранее.

Comment: Сохраните результат в дополнительный список, и либо перед сохранением проверяйте наличие такой же записи, либо удалите лишние записи, а потом - echo.
Либо сделайте отдельный запрос "SELECT distinct..." выводящий только уникальные данные для вывода результата.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не делайте запросы в цикле, это ужасная практика

Comment: А как, если $url - это массив
$quer = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `" . PREFIX . "_sites` WHERE `url` = '" . $url . "'");

Comment: @Folkey https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/in.php

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос решен. $sql = "SELECT `url`, `id` FROM `". PREFIX ."_sites` WHERE `url` IN ('". implode("','", array_keys($result_sql )) ."')";